# Commenting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, comments

What is the purpose of using `//` in the following code. If old browsers doesnt support javascript then the symbols `<!-- -->` will ignore js code. In case browsers support JS, these symbols `<!-- -->` will be ignored. Then wats the use of `//` symbols.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If old browsers doesnt support javascript then the symbols `<!-- -->` will ignore js code.

True, assuming HTML and for a definition of "old browsers" equal to "Netscape 1 era". [Don't use them today](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/).

> In case browsers support JS, these symbols `<!-- -->` will be ignored.

Only half true. Only the start of the comment is special cased. From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.2):

> The JavaScript engine allows the string "`<!--`" to occur at the start of a SCRIPT element, and ignores further characters until the end of the line. JavaScript interprets "`//`" as starting a comment extending to the end of the current line. This is needed to hide the string "`-->`" from the JavaScript parser.

Comment: great answer. much more concrete answer than mine!

Comment: but if we don't hide using `//` nothing worse happens. Code works as it should in firefox?

Comment: Browsers are really good at recovering from &^%$, but aren't always consistent in how they do it.

Comment: @sandbox: I guess it wasn't supported in old browsers. Although moderns browsers may allow it, the whole `<!--`/`//-->` stuff is not meant for them.

Comment: Impressive as always.  Your knowledge of the spec is incredible

Comment: “Only half true.” Actually, it is completely true. `-->` is treated as a `SingleLineComment` (equivalent to `//`) when it’s at the start of a line, optionally preceded by whitespace or `MultiLineComment`s. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18637940/96656).

Answer (score 4):

`--` is a JavaScript operator. It is used not to confuse the parser.

You really don't need those HTML comments anymore, BTW.

Comment: But why is `-->` in comments, and `<!--` not? Is `<!--` valid javascript then, and why (not)?

Comment: @Konerak - Quentin's answer is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-standard feature that browsers and JavaScript engines have always implemented.  Nowadays, it cannot be removed, as that would break backwards compatibility. It’s [detailed in ***the JavaScript / Web ECMAScript spec***](http://javascript.spec.whatwg.org/#comment-syntax):

> `<!--` must be treated as the start of a `SingleLineComment` —
>   equivalent to `//`.
>
> ```
> var x = true;
> <!-- x = false; // note: no syntax error
> x; // true
> ```
>
> `-->` at the start of a line, optionally preceded by whitespace or
>   `MultiLineComment`s, must be treated as a `SingleLineComment` —
>   equivalent to `//`.
>
> ```
> var x = true;
> --> x = false; // note: no syntax error
> x; // true
>
> var x = 1;
> /*
> multiline comment!
> x = 2;
> */ --> x = 3;
> x; // 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

See [HTML Comments and JavaScript](http://javascript.about.com/library/blhtmcmt.htm)

Answer (score 0):

they are also use so that old versions of netscape dont through errors: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/basicjavascript.html